# combine solutions of trig equation

Tags: trigonometry

I have two possible solutions of a trig equation :
$ x= \frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{2}{3}k\pi$ or  $x=\frac{5 \pi}{12}+\frac{2}{3}k\pi$ and I dont see how can one group them in one unique solution : $$ x = \frac{\pi}{12}+  \frac{k\pi}{3}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See that $$ x_1 = \frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{(2k) \pi}{3}$$ and

$$x_2 = \frac{5\pi}{12}+ \frac{2k\pi}{3} = \frac{\pi}{12}+ \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{2k\pi}{3} = \frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{3}$$

So $$x=\frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{n\pi}{3} =x_1$$ when $n$ is even
and $$x = \frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{n \pi}{3} =x_2$$ when $n$ is odd.